# Fast pixel comparisons with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

Can anyone help me optimize this algorithm? Currently it takes way too long looping through each pixel with iteritems, is there and opencv alternative algorithm that does it much faster?

I basically have two images and am overlaying one with a horizontal and vertical shift, that's what lbx,ubx,etc... is calculating. Then I loop through the overlapping area and calculate a cost function for it. It takes about 18 seconds for each translations though and looping through a simple 20x20 pixel grid translation takes 400 * 18 / 60 = 2 hours

AFTER EDIT: I think using numpy properly is the key here. Instead of accessing the pixels through calculating the position, I slice out the 2 images I'm comparing and then use izip to step through them at the same time and compare. It's still slow though, I think I'm misunderstanding something here.

EDIT 2: see code

I think the key is to use universal functions. I'm comparing two equally sized images and based and doing something based on how the pixels relate so it's not a standard universal function like add or multiply. Is it possible to create a custom one?

```
im1 = cv2.imread(url1, 5) #any  number over 5 is color
im2 = cv2.imread(url2, 5)

total = ubx * uby

proportion_dict = {}

for x1,x2 in itertools.izip(xrange(lbx+x,ubx+x),xrange(lbx,ubx)):
    for y1,y2 in itertools.izip(xrange(lby+y,uby+y),xrange(lby,uby)):

        if (im1[x1][y1] == im2[x2][y2]).all():
            pass
        else:
            key = str(clean_key(im1[x1][y1]))+str(clean_key(im2[x2][y2]))
            if key in proportion_dict:
                proportion_dict[key] += 1
            else:
                proportion_dict[key] = 1

### AFTER EDIT ####


im1_slice = im1[lby+y:uby+y,lbx+x:ubx+x]
im2_slice = im2[lby:uby,lbx:ubx]


for e1_row,e2_row in itertools.izip(im1_slice,im2_slice):

    for e1_element, e2_element in itertools.izip(e1_row,e2_row):

       dostuff()

## SECOND EDIT ###

#I've simplified the code to:

for e1_row,e2_row in itertools.izip(im1_slice.reshape(-1,3),im2_slice.reshape(-1,3)):
    doStuff()

#but it's still very slow
```

Comment: As you've found, manipulating pixels one by one in python is cumbersome and **very** slow, which is why the opencv python bindings already make use of [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Numpy allows you to operate on blocks of pixels (arrays, actually) at once, and the actual computation happens in highly optimized C code, making your code more readable and much faster. You should definitely [check out the tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial)

Comment: what does `clean_key` do?

Comment: So it is the slow part the use of itertools?

Comment: doesn't numpy already have similar optimizations

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20364174/1730674) at  [How do I avoid looping through an image pixel by pixel with python (opencv & numpy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362108/how-do-i-avoid-looping-through-an-image-pixel-by-pixel-with-python-opencv-num)