# How do I avoid looping through an image pixel by pixel with opencv & numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm looping through this image pixel by pixel and it's really slow. I have the 2 images I'm comparing sliced and flattened so each element is a 3 dimensional rgb value named `e1` and `e2`. It is very slow though. Is there some method using `opencv` or `numpy` that can speed this up?

What I'm doing here is performing pixel comparisons on images with binned colors (8 colors).
I'm reading from a jpeg though so what should be `[255,0,0]` becomes `[230,12,11]` so what `clean_key` does is threshold the values to the cleaner ones. Then I append the number of times this combination occurs to a dictionary. So for example `dict["255,0,0 0,0,255"]` might occur 300 times in this image which means there were 300 instances where `im1` had a red pixel and `im2` had a blue pixel.

```
for e1,e2 in itertools.izip(im1_slice.reshape(-1,3),im2_slice.reshape(-1,3)):
      key = str(clean_key(e1_row)) + str(clean_key(e2_row))
      if key in proportion_dict:
        proportion_dict[key] += 1
      else:
        proportion_dict[key] = 1           

return (proportion_dict,total)
```

Comment: I think we'll need more information here .. to vectorise this loop, the `clean_key` function will also need to be vectorised at the very least.  Also, a better explanation of what you want (your original purpose) might be useful since your current method might not be ideal.  For example, you might want to convert your images from color images to 8bit grayscale images, if you are really binning into 8 colors, then you don't have to have this confusing list-to-key thing.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. I was hoping that there was a fast method to loop through the pixels and that the bottleneck was in the accessing of the pixels. It looks like I'll have to consider this problem from the ground up with vector operations in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you want to do this is first compare each image to the color you want to see in that image, which makes a boolean mask where that image is the given color.  You don't need to flatten the images to do this.  This can be done by saying:

```
image == color
```

This works fine for grayscale images, but if `color` is actually along a third dimension, you want to make sure everything along that dimension matches (i.e., you want all of the r, g, and b components to match, so you use `np.all` along the last axis (`-1` gives the last axis):

```
np.all(image == color, axis=-1)
```

Which gives a 2d array of booleans where each element is `True` if that pixel matches `color` and `False` if not.  Do this for both images (and both colors) and then you'll have a mask where the color matches *both* images:

```
np.all(im1==c1, -1) & np.all(im2==c2, -1)
```

This not only tells you how many pixels match, but where they are (you could plot the above line and see dot at the points where they match).  If you just want the count, just use `np.sum` on the mask which counts `True` as `1`, and `False` as `0`.  All together:

```
def compare_colors(im1, im2, c1, c2):
    matches = np.all(im1==c1, -1) & np.all(im2==c2, -1)
    return matches.sum()
```

And to use/test it with random data:

```
>>> a = np.random.choice([0, 255], (20,20,3))
>>> b = np.random.choice([0, 255], (20,20,3))
>>> compare_colors(a, b, [255, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0])
12
```

But before you do that, with your real input, you want to "clean" your colors by a threshold.  You could easily do that with `np.where` which looks at each element of an array, and if a condition is met, gives one thing, and if not, gives another.  Here, if the value is less than `128`, it uses `0`, and otherwise uses `255`:

```
np.where(a<128, 0, 255)
```

In general, you could write a function like this, with the values above as defaults:

```
def clean(a, thresh=128, under=0, over=255):
    return np.where(a<128, under, over)
```

Of course to build up your dict of counts, you still have to loop through each color combination, but that's a short loop (`8*8`).  Here's a full run through:

```
# some fake data (has values between 0 and 255 for r, g, and b)
H, W = 20, 20
a = np.random.randint(0, 256, (H,W,3))
b = np.random.randint(0, 256, (H,W,3))

# clean the images:
ac = clean(a)
bc = clean(b)

# build a list of all pairs of all 8 colors using itertools.product:
col_combos = itertools.product(itertools.product((0,255), repeat=3), repeat=2)

# now apply the comparison to the images for each pair of colors
col_dict = { (c1,c2): compare_colors(ac, bc, c1, c2) for c1,c2 in col_combos }
```

Then, the keys for `col_dict` are actually tuples of tuples, which are much easier to deal with than strings, in my opinion.  Here's how you'd access an example key:

```
>>> col_dict[((0, 255, 255), (255, 0, 255))]
8
```

Comment: Thanks! Very detailed, it was really useful for getting used to numpy as well.

Comment: My pleasure! Just ask if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just thought to add that I'm getting a 7 fold increase in speed!